# what is more secure way to send sensitive data in MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, passwords, submit

Could you please advice me what is more secure way and what procedure to follow.

I have this page with password and other data to be sent. So what is the more secure way to send it in MVC3:
1) with ajax
2) or with submit button which post the data into the model and i have the model as input parameter of the method in the controller which handles the submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same: nor is secure unless you use SSL. Ajax is just an async http post/get, so technically they are equivalent if you talk about security.